# how could I change variable value into a target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, nested-loops

here I am again with another make issue Im trying to handle (hardly), I have set several values I want make to read, but when I try to change inside a loop it does not work; $(FOUND) stills being the same as it was first, what could I being doing bad? is other way to set variables or to change them into?

here's a part of my code related to this question:

```
$(shell for d in $(INPUT); \
        do \
            $(if $(FOUND) -eq 1, REL=$(REL)../); \
            $(if $(findstring $(WORD),$(INPUT)), \
                echo '$(WORD)../'; FOUND=1)\
        done)
```

$(FOUND) variable is defined outside but want it to change when it gets $(WORD)

any suggestion for that???

thank you so much

Comment: well, my way to do this loop is the same way as Im doing on bash shell but this not work; is that meening that could not manage shell loops with GNU Make?

Comment: You persist in writing complicated makefiles when you haven't yet learned how to write simple ones that work.

Comment: @Beta hey but..dont say that come on..Now Im dealind with my variables so well ...hahaha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with the code above, so much so that it is difficult to understand your intention. Here is a partial list (sorry if I sound like Microsoft clippy)

- The code `$(if $(FOUND) -eq 1, REL=$(REL)../)`, looks like a mix between gnu-make syntax and shell syntax.
- Your loop seems to be superfluous. You are not using the loop variable `d`, and you are using a construct that process the entire sequence. E.g.: `$(findstring $(WORD),$(INPUT)`
- It seems that you are trying to generate code like `echo '$(WORD)../'`, but the context of this code is unclear. If it is outside a rule, the code has no meaning. If it is inside a rule, it will evaluate too late to set a makefile variable. There is a way to work around this problem, but first you need to clarify your intention better.
- I can only suspect you intended to have `REL=$(REL)/..` or `REL=../$(REL)` but I can be mistaken.
- Lastly it is important to understand that what you really should do in a Makefile is to describe a dependency graph, and let make figure out the order of operation needed to be performed. So a procedural approach such as may inferred from your code above should be minimized.

---

**Edit:**

If I read you correctly, you are trying to achieve a tricky goal in Makefile. Let me assure you that your inexperience is not the only stumbling block you have. Writing good Makefiles is hard. If you have any control over this, I strongly suggest to have a look at some other build solutions. For example, [cmake](http://cmake.org/) can write good Makefiles for you.

If you are trying to calculate a base-dir or a relative-dir, please note that the concept of current-working-directory as saved in `$(CURDIR)` might or might not be what you expect.

For your question, you can indeed use a GNU make `$(foreach ...)` construct, but there are several functions that are designed to handle sequences without iterations, that might serve you better.

Comment: @Chen Levy, Thank you Chen, that really sounds good(not microsoft), probably my intentions are not clear but in fact, im mixing shell and make syntax, that it seems is not permited or something.
My main intention is to read a path, when make reads this path substitute each directory until it founds $(WORD) by ../ (its relative path) for me to change relative paths in several files.
but in this code, does not change $(REL) or $(FOUND) which defines that changes. Hope is more clearly now. And thanks a lot for your explanation it gives me more knowledge about that tool.
Greetings!

Comment: @Boris the Spider, if you liked his explanation, why didn't you vote it up (as I did)?

Comment: @Beta votes require reputation, Im new here mister...dont need to be so though with the others, including me. Hope you understand...

Comment: Beta, sorry as I said Im new here, but newer in GNU Make, Im just trying to understand and create a few makes correct. But this time need to learn about loops in make. Just a little more patience please...

Comment: Thank you Chen, is $(foreach what Im trying to set to make the variable change in $(FOUND) and $(REL) for them to change into relative path. Thanks for your suggestions. Actually Im working over $(PWD) to change path. Im supposing that 'tricky goal' as you call it is not so well with make and I need to implement pure GNU Make code to fix it, as functions and so...thank, your answers are so inspirational. Best wishes

Comment: My main problem actually is that make does not change my first defined variable as FOUND=0, I mean, when I get some word into $(CURDIR) I want make to change value with FOUND=1 to continue
It seems impossible for me to get this because make stills having FOUND=0 and the end of Makefile. any suggestion on this? thank you!

Comment: THanks for all, that was really helpful to find the solution